# Why I cannot launch manager gui in tomcat after editing server.xml and context.xml under conf folder?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I am able to start the tomcat 7.0.62 server. But I cannot launch the manager gui, after editing server.xml and context.xml. To verify, I deleted the unzipped tomcat folder and then unzipped a fresh copy, and now I was able to launch manager gui, because I haven't edited any files.This is how my tomcat-users.xml looks like

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="password" roles="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat1" password="tomcat1" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Same happens with tomcat 8.0.36 as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cannot launch the manager gui"?

Comment: I am able to see this screen http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-MlZBB0VePE4/ValOxKzqfzI/AAAAAAAAD08/Dab6J_wIKFc/s1600/localHostURL.jpg But if I click "Manager App" and enter username and password tomcat. I am not able to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out the issue. 
I have commented following piece of code in server.xml under conf directory of unzipped tomcat folder

```
   <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

I uncommented those. 
Also I had commented these

```
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
```

which I uncommented and it works like a charm.

Comment: So... you broke a bunch of stuff in your installation and then asked why it wouldn't work?

Comment: I was following a tutorial and I replaced these code blocks with what they gave, rather than adding those to the existing code. Newbie programmer. :)